# Change file name after path.getFileName

Tags: model-view-controller, .net

To upload image i'am using this code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FotoModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model != null && model.File != null)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(model.File.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), fileName);
                model.File.SaveAs(path);
                return View();
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Works fine, but is there option to change file name ?. I was trying do something like this:

```
fileName = FileMode(fileName, "user");
```

But there an exception: "System.IO.FileMode is a type but is used like a variable"

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't **Path.Combine()** allow for combining strings into a filename? So couldn't you simply do:

```
var fileName = "user";
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), fileName);
```

Comment: No, beacuse file is saving without any extension.

Answer (score 0):

In which case use the following to strip the extension then re-add it to the new filename:

```
string newName = "user";
fileName = newName + fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("."));
```